# How to achieve multiple inheritance with custom classes derived from Microsoft UserControl class?

Tags: c#, user-controls, multiple-inheritance

I'm writing a Word VSTO add-in that displays a Microsoft CustomTaskPane (CTP). At runtime, when you create a CustomTaskPane, you must first instantitate a Microsoft UserControl (UC) and provide it to the CTP Create method.

In my case, I'll be creating two CustomTaskPanes each with a custom UserControl designed by me. The user will be able to display (make visible) one CTP or the other or make both invisible. The user won't be able to display (make visible) both CTPs simeltaneously.

At design time:

- I created a class P1 that derives from Microsoft's UserControl class.
  I put a 2-row table (DevExpress) on the UC. I populated row 1 with a
  set of user controls specific to CTP #1. I left row two empty.

  I created a child class C1 that derives from P1. In the C1 designer,
  I can see P1's two row table. I populated row 2 (of P1's two row
  table) with another table (DevExpress) and populated it with a set of
  user controls specific to the P1 UC.

  I created a class P2 that derives from Microsoft's UserControl class.
  I put a 2-row table (DevExpress) on the UC. I populated row 1 with a
  set of user controls specific to CTP #2 (and different from CTP #1s).
  I left row two empty.

It's at this point that I realized I want to populate the 2nd row of P2's table with C1. In other words, although row 1 of P1 and P2 have a different set of controls, I want row 2 of P1 and P2 to be identical.

I went to edit C1 code to derive C1 from both P1 and P2, but that, of course, isn't allowed in C#.

*Note: Its important to note that in the end, I am going to have many child classes, i.e., C1 .. C50 and the user will be able to pick P1 or P2 and then after that Pick C1 .. C50. So, the child class coding needs to stay simple for the sake of code maintenance*

Is it possible to instantiate a class C1 and derive it from P1 or P2 dynamically (whether to derive from P1 or P2 would be based on user input)

Am I looking at this problem wrong? Should I be approaching it differently?

Currently, I've created an interface for P1 and P2 and I'm trying to figure out how to use it with C1 (and ultimarely with C2 .. C50) to acheive my goal, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: "Provide sample code": Do you mean code for everything I've described above short of the interface code? I can't provide the interface code - I can't figure out what to implement as an interface to solve the problem. I'm asking because when you create a UserControl class in VS, a boatload of code is auto generated. What code would be helpful to you?

Comment: A [mcve] would suffice.

Comment: Ok. Even so, that is significant, and I'll need a little time.  One requirement for working with a Word VSTO add-in MRE in Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2019) is that the development machine have Office 2016 (or newer) installed (or at least Word 2016). Does your development machine meet this requirement?

Comment: Just show me P1, P2 and C1.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - busy day at work yesterday :-). Please see [VS Project at GitHub](https://github.com/billcharlton/MRE-VSTO-UC). This is a working MRE. You can definitely view the source code, but there will be issues building + running the project due to a dependency on 3rd party packages. If needed, I can help with that. The download includes a PNG class diagram.